# How to show multiple images in a slideshow for a portfolio page

Tags: custom-post-types

I am planning to build a portfolio using custom post types, so the main portfolio page will show a "featured" image for each portfolio post.  Once you click on one of these images you will go to the actual post page for that portfolio item.

Once on this page I would like to show multiple images for this particular portfolio post.  So I am thinking of doing some sort of slideshow or possibly a big image with little thumbnail images that when clicked will load the larger version of the image into the big image slot.

So I am curious, when making a post for a portfolio item, how would I go about uploading and integrating multiple images for each item?

See the bottom of my mockup below, when you click on a thumbnail for a particular portfolio item, it will load a larger image

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to use the featured image (post thumbnail) as image for the portfolio listing and for the item itself you can use the native gallery with its shortcode: `[gallery]`.

Also if you'd like to use some kind of lightbox with it you can look/use the plugin 
[**`jQuery Lightbox For Native Galleries`**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jquery-lightbox-for-native-galleries/)

Comment: I think setting a featured image is the way to go for the main page image.  I'm not much of a fan of the lightbox idea for images though I am going more for something like this http://lucid.co.in/web_design/gallery.html on my actual `portfolio-single.php` Maybe I can modify the `[gallery]` output like you mentioned to do such a task

Comment: yep you can, as i say **look** at the plugin i linked to see who you can modify the gallery output.